# How is List<T> internally mapped?

Tags: .net, arrays, list, generics, clr

Does it internally get treated as an Array or does it get treated as a totally different type by the CLR?

I am trying to implement integer values to the list.

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(3);
lst.Add(4);
```

vs.

I create an Array of integers

```
int[] arr = new int[2];
arr[0] = 3;
arr[1] = 4;
```

Array returns better time span results. So why do people prefer List<>.

Comment: You could try [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) and take a look by yourself. The reason to have a dynamically growable/shrinkable list is that it is not fixed size like `Array` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<>` is an implementation of a data structure, which takes care of allocating memory on a on-demand basis; it allows for insertion and deletion at any index etc. Therefore it is much more convenient than a simple array.

Under the hood, the current `List<>` implementation uses an array for storage, and the overhead when doing array-like operations is minimal. The added convenience is usually worth the little (if at all relevant) performance difference. Adding items is typically faster because the list allocates chunks of memory and doesn't require a new allocation and copy on every add (compared to the pure array, where the `Length` is always bound to the size in memory).

Comment: So, what you are saying is, although negligible, `List<>` will provide a slower response, in terms of _Speed_, than an `Array`?

Comment: Of course. List<T> is an abstraction over array, and abstractions cost extra CPU cycles. Howevrr, I agree with Lucero, under normal conditions, List is more than fast enough.

Comment: The "response time" is typically irrelevant, the request gets passed through to the underlying array after a (fast and cheap) bounds check. This is probably even inlined by the runtime, so that it doesn't even need an additional call.

Answer (score 1):

A normal random access list typically has an internal array. The .NET `List<T>` implementation does this. Other implementations such as `LinkedList<T>` uses chains of elements with references instead of arrays. More exotic lists may use trees internally for ordering.

The internal array in `List<T>` is initialised with a short length (4 I believe), and if you try to add outside the max bounds of the array, it is expanded. Since this can be time consuming (the array needs to be copied), the array is doubled in size, i.e. when you add the 5th element the internal array is resized to length 8 and so on.

Comment: I remember reading, that `List<>` Data Structure is optimized for _Speed_, whereas `Array` DS is optimized for _Memory_. You seem to be contradicting the fact that `List<>` is optimized for _Speed_. (when we say that it gets re-sized and reallocated, when moving out of bounds)

Comment: I don't agree with that distinction. A List<T> HAS an array internally, so is essentially no different from an array storage-wise.  You pay a tiny performance penalty with the list, and for that cost you get a dynamic/resizable collection. So in conclusion the largest difference between list and array, is that you can always ADD things to a list.

Comment: @bugbuster, if you want to add an item to an array (so that `Length` increases, that is, not just *change* an existing item), you have to re-allocate the array too. The list will grow in bigger chunks and keep track of the number of used elements of the array, thereby it is faster for sequential adds.